# Pm2 is unable to run nodejs microservices after nodejs upgradation from v10.24.1 to v16.15.1

Tags: linux, process-management, node.js, npm

I have upgraded from nodejs 10.24.1 to 16.15.1 on my centos machine. and updated my pm2 to latest version, and ran pm2 update all the microservice process where running sucesffully. But on rebbot the Pm2 is unable to start any process and erroors out as  In memory Pm2 is out of data. This happens on every reboot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.